# How to check if a shell command is over in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell

Let's say that I have this simple line in python:

```
os.system("sudo apt-get update")
```

of course, apt-get will take some time untill it's finished, how can I check in python if the command had finished or not yet?

Edit: this is the code with Popen:

```
     os.environ['packagename'] = entry.get_text()
     process = Popen(['dpkg-repack', '$packagename'])
     if process.poll() is None:
       print "It still working.."
     else:
       print "It finished"
```

Now the problem is, it never print "It finished" even when it really finish.

Comment: why do you want to check?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i want to run another command when the first command (dpkg-repack) is finished, the problem is like i said in another comment that it doesn't send a signal that it finished at all, thats why i was looking for another way to know if it had finished.

Comment: does your next command not run? Post the code you are trying to run

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I added the code to the post.

Comment: Can you post all the code, if you just want to run commands in bash why do you need to check if they are finished?

Comment: The code is too long and has nothing important than the above code, what i am doing is that i am running a python program before the command start, then i am running the dpkg-repack command, and then i want to use killall to kill the python program i started when dpkg-repack finish only, but the problem is that dpkg-repack is not finishing at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation states it:

> This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and
>   has the same limitations

The C call to `system` simply runs the program until it exits. Calling `os.system` blocks your python code until the bash command has finished thus you'll know that it is finished when `os.system` returns. If you'd like to do other stuff while waiting for the call to finish, there are several possibilities. The preferred way is to use the [subprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) module.

```
from subprocess import Popen
...
# Runs the command in another process. Doesn't block
process = Popen(['ls', '-l'])
# Later
# Returns the return code of the command. None if it hasn't finished
if process.poll() is None: 
    # Still running
else:
    # Has finished
```

Check the link above for more things you can do with `Popen`

For a more general approach at running code concurrently, you can run that in another [thread](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html) or [process](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html). Here's example code:

```
from threading import Thread
...
thread = Thread(group=None, target=lambda:os.system("ls -l"))
thread.run()
# Later
if thread.is_alive():
   # Still running
else:
   # Has finished
```

Another option would be to use the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) module.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `subprocess` module is the way to go in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, i tried the Popen way, but the problem is that i am executing dpkg-repack command , and looks like when it finish packaging the .deb files, it lags or something and it doesn't send a signal that it had finished, and the code will be blocked even with Popen.

Edit: i tried apt-get, and it has the same problem (it doesn't send a signal that it had finished).

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem, but you are now missing `sudo`. Try `Popen(["sudo", "dpkg-repack", "$package"])`

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff i am running the whole application using gksu.

Answer (score 1):

[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) will actually wait for the command to finish and return the exit status (format dependent format).

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` is blocking; it calls the command waits for its completion, and returns its return code.

So, it'll be finished once `os.system` returns.

If your code isn't working, I think that could be caused by one of `sudo`'s quirks, it refuses to give rights on certain environments(I don't know the details tho.).